# Angular js, controller not posting data to the server through API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http-post

I am very new to angular js, I am trying to POST data to the server using the API I have created:

```
 function addmovie_post() {

 {
    $genre = $this->post('genre');
    $cast = $this->post('cast');    
    $director = $this->post('director');
    $title = $this->post('title');
    $price = $this->post('price');
    $image = $this->post('image');

    }
{
    //check for empty parameters

    if(empty($title) || empty($cast) || empty($genre) || empty($image) || empty($price) || empty($director))
     { 
            $info->status = 'failure';
            $info->error->code = 13;
            $info->error->text = 'one or more parameters missing';
    //$info->error->text .= $title." ".$cast." ".$genre." ".$director;
            $this->response($info, 400);
    }
}
{   // check for  duplicate record
        $this->load->database();
        $sql = 'select count(id) as records from movies where title = "'.$title.'" and cast = "'.$cast.'";';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->row();
        if ($data->records == "1") {
            $info->status = 'failure';
            $info->error->code = 18;
            $info->error->text = 'duplicate record';
            $this->response($info, 400);
        }
    }
$this->load->database();
$info = array('id'=> null, 'title'=>$title, 'cast'=>$cast,'genre'=>$genre, 'image'=>$image, 'price'=>$price,'director'=>$director );
$this ->db->insert('movies', $info);
$data->title = $title;
$data->cast = $cast;
$data->genre = $genre;
$data->price = $price;
$data->image = $image;
$data->director = $director;
$data->message = 'The movie has been added';
$this->response($data,201);
}
```

My API is working fine.
This is the angular code with the HTML, I am not getting any errors in the console. But The data is not getting sent through, console.log does not display any data.

```
  var app = angular.module('postapp', []);

   app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

 var formData = {
 title: "default",
 director: "default",
 cast: "default",
 genre: "default",
 image: "default",
 price: "default"
  };


 $scope.submitForm = function() {

 $http({

    url: "http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4078078/moviereviews/v1.0/index.php/movie/addmovie",
    data: $scope.form,
    method: 'POST',
    headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}

}).success(function(data){

    console.log("OK", data)

}).error(function(error){"ERR", console.log($scope.error.error)})
 };

  });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="postapp">

    <form name="formData" ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        title:    <br/><input type="text" ng-model="form.title">    <br/><br/>
        price: <br/><input type="text" ng-model="form.price"> <br/><br/>
                    genre:    <br/><input type="text" ng-model="form.genre">    <br/><br/>
                    image:    <br/><input type="text" ng-model="form.image">    <br/><br/>
        cast:    <br/><input type="text" ng-model="form.cast">    <br/><br/>
        director: <br/><input type="text" ng-model="form.director"> <br/><br/>
```

```
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: On first glance, I don't see $scope.form defined anywhere.   At the top of your controller try `$scope.form = {}` or `$scope.form = formData` after you've set those values.

Comment: I have added $scope.form = formdata, it does not work still, But I have left it there as i know I still need it.

Comment: try to stringify data and send it via http mehtod ; `data:JSON.stringify($scope.form)`

Comment: That does not work either

Comment: When I console.log(formData) even before sending http request it does not do anything in the console

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb.  Remove the action from your controller and see if it works.

> Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the >server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain action, data->action, or x-action attributes.

The other problem you may have is a cross domain issue.  See if it works on a local url.

Comment: I have tried that, and taken out action it still does not work. But the problem is if I console.log data before even making a post request it does not display anything

Comment: Create a plunker/fiddle to demonstrate the issue otherwise we can only speculate.  Also you may try including the html for the entire page. Maybe missing ng-app.